# Passing data to NUnit 3.x extension

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

When I define extension using interface ITestEventListener it can only accept `string report` as parameter.

How could I pass big data, such as screenshots?

Comment: I would use a TestAttachment https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#addtestattachment-37

Comment: And what about to passing data in realtime? The only way to do it I found is to pass data to `TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("Some text");` and then parse it in the extension.